# Can't plot gradient for a circular mesh

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot the gradient of a function over a circular mesh. To create the circular mesh I have the following code

```
r0 = 6; 
N = 40;
r = linspace(0, r0, N);
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, N);
[Theta, R] = meshgrid(theta, r);
[X, Y] = pol2cart(Theta, R); % X,Y grid of a circular mesh on Cartesian Coordinate
```

I have a simple function

```
distanceFunc = r0^2 - (X.^2 + Y.^2);
```

which I could easily plot the [`surf`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGv3M.jpg) and [`contour`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpB5F.jpg) plots for. But I also need the gradient, I am using the `gradient` function in matlab like so:

```
[u, v] = gradient(distanceFunc);
```

and then `quiver` to plot the gradient vectors.

```
quiver(X, Y, u, v)
```

but I'm not getting the right directions for the [quiver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANMJV.jpg) plot. There's probably something to change between the Polar/Cartesian coordinates but I can't seem to find what it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gradient` assumes that your `distanceFunc` is evaluated on a rectangular domain with equal grid spacing in the `x` and `y` directions. Clearly that is not the case here.

There are two options, either interpolate (using `interp2`) from a rectangular grid on to a circular grid for plotting;

```
r0 = 6; 
N = 41;
r = linspace(0, r0, N);
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, N);
[Theta, R] = meshgrid(theta, r);
[X2, Y2] = pol2cart(Theta, R);

[X,Y]=meshgrid(linspace(-r0,r0,N)); %// rectangular grid for gradient
distanceFunc = r0^2 - (X.^2 + Y.^2);    
[u, v] = gradient(distanceFunc);

u2=interp2(X,Y,u,X2,Y2); %// interpolate u and v back on to circular grid
v2=interp2(X,Y,v,X2,Y2);

quiver(X2,Y2,u2,v2)
```

or, use symbolic algebra to find the gradient functions and plot them;

```
r0 = 6; 
N = 41;
r = linspace(0, r0, N);
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, N);
[Theta, R] = meshgrid(theta, r);
[X2, Y2] = pol2cart(Theta, R);

syms X Y %// initialise symbolic variables
distanceFunc = r0^2 - (X.^2 + Y.^2); %// define distanceFunc

%// Find derivatives in each direction and convert to numeric functions with matlabFunction
u=matlabFunction(diff(distanceFunc,X),'vars',{'X','Y'});
v=matlabFunction(diff(distanceFunc,Y),'vars',{'X','Y'});

%// plot the result
quiver(X2,Y2,u(X2,Y2),v(X2,Y2))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was hoping to keep the circular mesh because it generated better 3D plots.